# Approximate Maximum Weight Matching

Tags: graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, linear-programming, randomized-algorithms, matching

I am looking for an approximated (or randomized) maximum weight matching algorithm. Do you have any suggestion for me?

In my problem, I have a bipartite graph with N abound 1000 (#vertices on each side) and the Hungarian algorithm takes too much time to be an option for my case.

- the weight on edges are real numbers but it's ok to round them to integer numbers
- I have a brute-force greedy implementation, however, I am looking for something more sophisticated

Thanks

Comment: How much time is too much? I think even a linear programming solver would have no problem with that size instance.

Comment: I need something in the order of 100 milliseconds or even less. Do you think it's feasible?
Do you have any suggestion for the LP solver? C++ or Python?

Comment: See the paper and references there in. http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try Sage's implementation. It uses LP, but I don't think that you would get something so large in less than 100milliseconds. Greedy probabilistic would be nice in this case I guess.

http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html#sage.graphs.graph.Graph.matching